# Use selected value as a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, dataexplorer

I'm writing [a data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/208564/lowest-score-accepted-answers) to find the accepted answers with the lowest score, and this part works fine:

```
SELECT TOP 25 a.Id as [Post Link],
              a.Score as Score,
              (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM Votes
               WHERE PostId = a.Id AND
                     VoteTypeId = 2) AS [Upvotes],
              (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM Votes
               WHERE PostId = a.Id AND
                     VoteTypeId = 3) AS [Downvotes]
FROM Posts q INNER JOIN Posts a ON q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
WHERE a.PostTypeId = 2
ORDER BY a.Score ASC
```

However, when I tried to work out what score the person who posted the answer has, I can't get it to accept the `[Upvotes]` and `[Downvotes]` columns I'm selecting as parameters, i.e.:

```
SELECT TOP 25 a.Id as [Post Link],
              a.Score as Score,
              (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM Votes
               WHERE PostId = a.Id AND
                     VoteTypeId = 2) AS [Upvotes],
              (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM Votes
               WHERE PostId = a.Id AND
                     VoteTypeId = 3) AS [Downvotes],
              (15 + (([Upvotes] * 10) - ([Downvotes] * 2))) AS [Answerer's Reputation]
FROM Posts q INNER JOIN Posts a ON q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
WHERE a.PostTypeId = 2
ORDER BY a.Score ASC
```

I'm told `[Upvotes]` and `[Downvotes]` are not a valid column names:

> Invalid column name 'Upvotes'. Invalid column name 'Downvotes'.

How do I indicate that `[Upvotes]` is the same value I've just declared: `AS [Upvotes]`? Or is this simply not possible and I'd have to do it manually as a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the calculated columns are calculated at the same time as when you are referencing the columns, so SQL doesn't know about them.

This would be one solution

```
SELECT A.[Post Link], 
   A.Score, 
   A.Upvotes, 
   A.Downvotes, 
   (15 + (([Upvotes] * 10) - ([Downvotes] * 2)))AS [Answerer's Reputation]
FROM(SELECT TOP 25 P.Id AS [Post Link], 
                 P.Score AS Score, 
                 (
   SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM Votes
    WHERE Postid = P.Id
      AND Votetypeid = 2)AS [Upvotes], 
                 (
   SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM Votes
    WHERE Postid = P.Id
      AND Votetypeid = 3)AS [Downvotes]
     FROM Posts Q
          INNER JOIN Posts P ON Q.Acceptedanswerid = P.Id
    WHERE P.Posttypeid = 2)A
 ORDER BY A.Score ASC;
```

Comment: Almost perfect, it should have been `WHERE P.Posttypeid = 2 ORDER BY Score ASC) AS A` instead of  `WHERE P.Posttypeid = 2)A
 ORDER BY A.Score ASC`, but you got me there so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you treat upvotes and downvotes as a table? And then, you can work as you want.

You can do that by 2 ways: Table-value functions or inline tables.
Picking your code should be something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 25 a.Id as [Post Link],
          a.Score as Score,
          [Upvotes].CountVotes as Upvotes,
          [Downvotes].CountVotes as DOwnvotes,
          (15 + (([Upvotes].CountVotes * 10) - ([Downvotes].CountVotes * 2))) AS    [Answerer's Reputation]
  FROM Posts q INNER JOIN Posts a ON q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as CountVotes
           FROM Votes
           WHERE PostId = a.Id AND
                 VoteTypeId = 2) AS [Upvotes],

          (SELECT COUNT(*) as CountVotes
           FROM Votes
           WHERE PostId = a.Id AND
                 VoteTypeId = 3) AS [Downvotes]
WHERE a.PostTypeId = 2
ORDER BY a.Score ASC
```